# Azure DevOps with SonarCloud not finding tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sonarcloud

I'm using SonarCloud with AzureDevops.

The sequence in my YAML file is:

1. Restore NuGet
2. Sonar Prepare
3. Build solution
4. Run tests
5. Sonar Analyze
6. Sonar Publish

I don't specify any output locations (at least, not knowingly).

When the tests run, I get the following output:

> Test results files: d:\a_temp\TestResults\VssAdmin.....trx

But when the Sonar Analysis step executes, I get the following output:

> Looking for TRX files in: d:\a\1\TestResults

So....the paths don't match.

Do I:

- tell Azure to write the tests to a different folder?
- or, do I tell Sonar where to find the test results?

I'm guessing the second option might be easier - in a different solution I've not yet set up, there are many test projects....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in VSTest task, test results are stored in `$(Agent.TempDirectory)/TestResults` by default. You could change it to `$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Rather than change all our build scripts just for Sonar, decided to instead hard-code the path into Sonar (`d:\a_temp\`).  If it proves to be dynamic and changes over time then we'll have to back-track and change our build scripts to match Sonar.